# как сплитить list по ключевому символу

Tags: java, строки, list

У меня есть файл, в котором лежит строка, где каждое значение разделено пробелом, мне надо разделить каждое значение через пробел.
В файле строка "a b c", нужно их вынести в отдельный лист, в котором будет значение [a, b, c], чтобы я мог найти индекс символа.

Тут лежит вся строка:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(Paths));
    List<String> string = Collections.singletonList(in.nextLine());
```

Есть ли какая-то аналогия метода .split(" ");, но для list'a?

Comment: А чем вас метод .split(" ") не устраивает?

Comment: нужно использовать для чтения на ввод именно list

Comment: string.get(0).split(" ")[1] , вы получите символ b из строки "a b c"

Comment: спасибо, просто не знал что так можно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так:

```
    List<String> newStr = Arrays.asList(string.get(0).split(" "));
```